# How to call a function which resides inside the component from parent controller in AngularJS 1.8

Tags: angularjs, frontend, angular-components

I have demoComponent.js which is being called in the template xyz.html of the controller xyzController. Now, I want to execute a function which resides in the demoComponent from xyzController. The angularjs version 1.8.

Example Code:

### xyzController.js

```
function xyzController($scope) {
   const vm = this;

   vm.$onInit = () => {
      vm.trigger_update(); // It works in AngularJS 1.5, but, not in 1.8
   };
}
```

### xyz.html

```
<div ng-controller="xyzController as xyzController">
   <demo-component ng-if="some condition" on-update="xyzController.trigger_update"></demo-component>
</div>
```

### demoComponent.js

```
const demoComponent = {
    bindings: {
       on_update: '=onUpdate',
    },
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    controller: function($scope) {
      const vm = this;

      vm.on_update = () => { // some functionality }
    }
}
```

Need help

I should be able to call component controller function from xyzController.

Comment: Dont use '=' binding for functions.

Comment: I tried without using "=". It didn't worked.